# Execute XCUITests on static iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode9, ios-ui-automation, ios-frameworks, xcuitest

I have developed a static iOS `.framework` but during its development, we figured out that its manual testing is taking much time due to a huge number of datasets.

In order to minimize its testing time, we have decided to automate this process so we can have less testing time which will empower our Quality Assurance team to test datasets within no time.

Specifically, we want to execute `XCUITests` on one of the framework's `UIViewController` on which SDK is taking `UITextfield` input i.e. we want to automate form filling exercise for that particular view controller.

I have successfully captured activities and interactions using `XCUITest` but I want to execute those test functions at the time when a user lands on that view controller. Currently, those test functions are executed on time i.e. even SDK is not being initiated.

My question is, is it possible to execute `XCUITests` on the static iOS framework? If yes, is it possible to start execution on the desired event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCUITests execute in a separate process and build as a separate target, so it is impossible to start them from within the app as you describe. Also, XCUITests can only interact with what VoiceOver / accessibility can interact with, so you must have some sort of application installed on a device or simulator to execute tests against.

The recommended approach is to build a simple sample application that loads your framework / UI and then execute your XCUITests against the sample application.